# How to remove 1 segment from UISegmentControll

Tags: ios, objective-c, hide, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a `UISegmentControll` with 2 segments. At a certain point in the program, I want to hide 1 segment. (I'd prefer hiding than removing, but if the only way is to remove, I'm all ears.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one to set it enables / disables

```
[segmentedControl setEnabled:NO forSegmentAtIndex:0];
```

Or remove by this

```
[segmentedControl removeSegmentAtIndex:4 animated:NO];
```

Comment: I need to either hide or remove it. :)

Comment: just modified the answer.

Comment: The minimum segments in `UISegmentControl` is 2, and that's all I have, so I therefore wanna hide it. But thanks anyway!!

Comment: You might need to implement your own segment UI instead of using  **UISegmentControl** to achieve this feature as you describe

Comment: Do you mean like `UIButtons`?

Comment: Yup, use *UIView + UIButton*.